# rpcgen in Windows 7 - no preprocessor found

Tags: c, windows, rpc

I created an IDL like this:

```
struct intpair { 
    int a; 
    int b; 
}; 
program ADD_PROG { 
    version ADD_VERS { 
         int ADD(intpair) = 1; 
     } = 1; 
} = 0x23451111;
```

I installed rpcgen, but when I try to compile this with

```
rpcgen -C add.x
```

or

```
rpcgen add.x
```

the error-message below is shown

> cannot find any C preprocessor (cpp)

I have a gcc installed.

---

Ok, the command is now working, but it returns an error-message.

```
C:\Users\baco\Desktop\rpcTest>rpcgen -C -Y "C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin" add.x
```

produced the output:

```
Der Befehl "C:/Program" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden.
```

So it produces an error message (the command was not found or misspelled) but also the following files are created:
add.h, add_clnt.c, add_svc.c, add_xdr.c

When I add the -a flag to produce additional template-code, this error-message appears:

```
rpcgen: unable to open Makefile.add=C:\Ú☻<ms\: m
```

Maybe a problem with the path again ?

Comment: Use -Y option to specify where gcc is installed.

Comment: I tried: rpcgen  -Y "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin" add.x      But sadly it gives me "fopen: No such file or directory

Comment: Surely you have to speak with a Unix lisp?  Use forward slashes.

Comment: C:\Users\baco\Desktop\rpcTest>rpcgen -Y "C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/
bin" add.x
Zugriff verweigert
fopen
: No such file or directory

Comment: Where did you get your rpcgen from ? Can you verify that `cpp` and `gcc` is in your PATH ? (just opern a command windows and run `gcc` and `cpp)

Comment: gcc or cpp are running correctly from the cmd

Comment: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sunrpc.htm is the source for my rpcgen

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -Y flag to specify the path of where cpp is. On windows for instance this might be: rpcgen -Y c:\pathtogcc myfile.x

In answer to the fopen error above its a permissions problem ie. Access Denied. On windows for instance you need to run the cmd prompt as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Check these:

1. Is `gcc` in the PATH? How did you install `gcc`? Cygwin or something else?
2. Is the C preprocessor named `cpp`? (On some systems it is `cccp`)

If all else fails, create a script named `cpp.bat` that calls `gcc -E` with all arguments.

Comment: gcc is in the path. I installed DevCpp an just added the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin" to the path. I don't know how to create such script cpp.bat.?

Comment: The preprocessor is named cpp.exe

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did and it worked on Windows 7 system: 
(1) Installed cygwin 32 bit with following packages 
   rpcgen
   gcc-core
   all the isl libraries (cpp.exe requires isl, isl10, cloog-isl, ...)
(2) added cygwin\bin to PATH (in dos)
(3) ran rpcgen in windows DOS prompt, and with this it is able to generate the .h and .c files.

From your description, it appears that your rpcgen is looking for cpp not cpp.exe and dont know of any way to change that, so, choosing the right rpcgen that looks for cpp.exe is the way to go. I did look at the rpcgen code and it appears that it looks for cpp or cpp.exe depending on the OS setting.

Comment: Yes, this is working, but when I try to make the executables with make, it gives me an error.

Comment: C:\Users\baco\Desktop\rpcTest>make
cc -g    -c -o add_clnt.o add_clnt.c
In file included from add_clnt.c:7:0:
add.h:9:21: fatal error: rpc/rpc.h: No such file or directory
 #include <rpc/rpc.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'add_clnt.o' failed
make: *** [add_clnt.o] Error 1

Comment: I added C:\cygwin\usr\include\tirpc\rpc to the path. Now there are other errors.

Comment: My build step has next step as replace rpc/rpc.h in the source.c with stdint.h and rpc/types.h etc. So, essentially, rpc/rpc.h needs to be removed and equivalent needs to be obtained from elsewhere. Since my cross-compiler package had rpc/types.h it worked for me (for my program).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't like the spaces in the path to the preprocessor.